# Unable to start application after upgrading jackson-databind version

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jackson-databind

I am working on a spring boot application, I want to upgrade  `jackson-databind` from **2.9.10.2** to **2.10.2**. Below is snippet from my pom.xml and error I am getting after upgrading dependency :
**pom.xml :**

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

[image: Dependency hierarchy]
**ERROR:**

> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report
>   re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 13-03-2020
>   17:38:52.660||ERROR|o.s.boot.SpringApplication:821|Application run
>   failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f3fa4d]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:389)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1202)
>     at
>   com.finicity.accountowner.AccountOwnerApplication.main(AccountOwnerApplication.java:29)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]:
>   Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f3fa4d]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622)
>     ... 19 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration':
>   Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f3fa4d]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1883)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider.ifAvailable(ObjectProvider.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.configureMessageConverters(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerComposite.configureMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurerComposite.java:137)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.configureMessageConverters(DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.java:118)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getMessageConverters(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:745)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:563)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:450)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52ad7f39.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$6()
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52ad7f39$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$94866013.invoke()
>     at
>   org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$52ad7f39.requestMappingHandlerAdapter()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
>     ... 20 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate
>   [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f3fa4d]:
>   Constructor threw exception; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300)
>     ... 58 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter'
>   defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:509)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.addCandidateEntry(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1431)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveMultipleBeans(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1277)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.resolveStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1932)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.orderedStream(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1926)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.(HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.java:62)
>     at
>   org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1f3fa4d.()
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
>     ... 60 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jacksonObjectMapper' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration$JacksonObjectMapperConfiguration.class]:
>   Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:570)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
>     ... 83 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class
>   [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] from ClassLoader
>   [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@18b4aac2]   at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:367)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:432)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:406)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1077)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:567)
>     ... 93 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/fasterxml/jackson/core/StreamReadFeature  at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489)
>     ... 99 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.core.StreamReadFeature  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   ... 103 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: from bottom 6th line shows ClassNotFoundException, change  com.fasterxml.jackson.core version from 2.10.2 to 2.10.3. https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.10.3/bundle

Comment: @JosePraveen Already tries doing so

Comment: What are you doing in your code that makes you need to exclude jackson-databind instead of using it as a transitive dependency?

Comment: @alainlompo I have to upgrade it because of a vulnerability

Answer (score 8):

You usually can't just rip out a dependencies dependency and replace it with another version. It might work but doesn't have to and with jackson you seem out of luck. If there was any refactoring or changes to the API of the inner dependency that's used by the outer one, you'll see `ClassNotFoundException` like you do or `MethodNotFound` ones.

you will need to update your `com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml` to version 2.10.2 (or even 2.10.3.

Comment: I'd already done that before posting the question, just that missed to mention. Did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

@Nicktar was partially correct, issue was with `jackson-core`. `jackson-core` resolved from `jackson-dataformat-xml`(**2.10.3**) was version **2.9.9**, explicitly bumping it to required **2.10.3** fixed the issue. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Can you please share the pom which worked for fixing the jackson version?

Comment: @TZ-EZ It is `2.10.3`, but I'd to override `jackson-core` with same verion

Comment: Thanks @NisargPatil. I was struggling with exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For later readers: importing `jackson-bom` and not specifying individual dependency versions is one way to avoid some of these version-skew issues.